# How to fix limax.zdb.XError: dbhome "zdb" not exist?

Tags: java, eclipse

here is the error:

```
`limax.zdb.XError: dbhome "zdb" not exist
at limax.zdb.Zdb.testMeta(Zdb.java:130)
at limax.zdb.Zdb.start(Zdb.java:144)
at limax.provider.XmlConfig$StartZdb.lambda$0(XmlConfig.java:410)
at limax.xmlconfig.Service$Loader$TaskList.run(Service.java:108)
at limax.xmlconfig.Service$Loader.runTaskBeforeEngineStart(Service.java:257)
at limax.xmlconfig.Service$Loader.startNetEngine(Service.java:298)
at limax.xmlconfig.Service.startNetEngine(Service.java:350)
at limax.xmlconfig.Service.run(Service.java:372)
at forview.server.Main.main(Main.java:8)`
```

here is what's in my service-server.xml:

```
`<Zdb autoKeyInitValue="0" autoKeyStep="4096"
    checkpointPeriod="60000" corePoolSize="30" dbhome="zdb"
    deadlockDetectPeriod="1000"
    defaultTableCache="limax.zdb.TTableCacheLRU"
    edbCacheSize="65536" edbLoggerPages="16384" jdbcPoolSize="5"
    marshalN="1" marshalPeriod="-1" procPoolSize="10"
    schedPoolSize="5" snapshotFatalTime="200" zdbVerify="true">
    <Procedure maxExecutionTime="0" retryDelay="100" retryTimes="3" trace="WARN"/>
</Zdb>`
```

Probably I was trying to build a provider using limax in eclipse, but when I run it something goes wrong.Can someone please help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I create a new folder named "zdb" in my project and everything is ok now. orz